# How is the Monitor class implemented?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

How is the `Monitor` class implemented? Do it simply use the Win32 methods `CreateCriticalSection`, `LeaveCriticalSection` etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it simply use the Win32 methods ...

No, it [is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kad9xah9%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) a s being "fully managed" (no interop)

It reportedly uses Interlocked .